# understanding \ modifying Oracle Text IDF (inverse document frequency) scoring

Tags: oracle-text

Oracle Text uses a variation of IDF scoring.
The exact algorithm isn't documented.

In scenario the score appears to be different than the score I get when computing IDF manually

I'd like to understand how oracle computes the score, and possibly modify it.

- Is there a methods to modify the scoring algorithm?
- it appears the table DR$indexname$I contains the term frequency in the TOKEN_COUNT field - us this correct?
- is the structure of the DR$ tables documented?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to modify the scoring algorithm using a query template, e.g.:

```
select id from docs where CONTAINS (text,
'<query>
<textquery grammar="CONTEXT" lang="english"> mustang </textquery>
<score datatype="float" algorithm="DEFAULT" normalization_expr =Ódoc_score+SDATA(price)Ó/>
</query>')>0"
```

Not much more info here [4.1.17 Alternative and User-defined Scoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm#i1007605)